# Get header of csv using jackson-dataformat-csv

Tags: java, csv, jackson

I using `jackson-dataformat-csv` library. I want parse `CSV` file. I have this code:

```
 CsvMapper csvMapper = new CsvMapper();
        CsvSchema csvSchema = csvMapper.typedSchemaFor(Map.class).withHeader();
        List<Map<String, String>> csvRows;
        try {
            MappingIterator<Map<String, String>> it = csvMapper.readerFor(Map.class)
                    .with(csvSchema.withColumnSeparator(';'))
                    .readValues(file.getInputStream());
            csvRows = it.readAll();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error("Unable to read csv document: ", ex);
        }
```

I want get column names from this file. But I don't understand how to make it. I try:

```
csvSchema._columns
```

But, It is empty object. Too I make this:

```
csvSchema.column(0)
```

I get error:

```
Method threw 'java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException' exception.
```

Obviously, columns object is empty. Why? How I get array of column names from `CSV`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need column names you have them as keys in `Map` returned by `MappingIterator`:

```
CsvMapper csvMapper = new CsvMapper();
CsvSchema csvSchema = csvMapper.typedSchemaFor(Map.class).withHeader();

MappingIterator<Map<String, String>> it = csvMapper.readerFor(Map.class)
        .with(csvSchema.withColumnSeparator(','))
        .readValues(csvFile);

System.out.println("Column names: " + it.next().keySet());
```

Answer (score 6):

the fields are not in `CsvSchema` until you get the Parser from `MappingIterator`

a working example:

```java
CsvSchema schema = (CsvSchema) objectMappingIterator.getParser().getSchema();
        Iterator<CsvSchema.Column> iterator = schema.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            CsvSchema.Column next = iterator.next();
            next.getName();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely an overkill but here's another working solution using the parser schema:

```
    CsvMapper csvMapper = new CsvMapper();
    CsvSchema csvSchema = CsvSchema.emptySchema()
            .withHeader()
            .withColumnSeparator(';')
            .withNullValue("")
            .withoutQuoteChar();
    String source = "\"Column1\";\"Column2\";\"Column3\"\n" +
            "\"Value1\";\"Value2\";\"Value3\"";

    MappingIterator<Map<String, String>> mappingIterator = csvMapper
            .readerFor(Map.class)
            .with(csvSchema)
            .readValues(source.getBytes());

    FormatSchema parserSchema = mappingIterator.getParserSchema();

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"\"[^\"]*\"", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    String input = parserSchema.toString();//[CsvSchema: columns=[""Column1""/STRING,""Column2""/STRING,""Column3""/STRING], header? true, skipFirst? false, comments? false, any-properties? N/A]
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

    List<String> columnHeaders = new ArrayList<>();
    while (matcher.find()) {
        columnHeaders.add(matcher.group().replace("\"", ""));
    }
    System.out.println(columnHeaders);//[Column1, Column2, Column3]
```